# In what Folder are Dock Applications are stored?

Tags: dock

At the bottom of my screen of my Mac I have a dock with different shortcuts inside.

But.. **where** are these shortcuts stored? In what folder exactly?

Answer (score 12):

The "links" to the apps are stored in the file ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist in the key **persistent-apps** with ~ being the "shortcut" to /Users/yourusername:

[image]

In the example above I expanded the entries for *App Store*  and *Launchpad*.  The only exception is the Finder.app. Probably it's a fixed entry "injected" by Dock.app itself.

Normally, each user has its own com.apple.dock.plist file.

Comment: I wouldn't use the term "injected" in reference to Finder in the Dock. The Dock Tile presence and position for Finder in the Dock are hardcoded within the `/System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/MacOS/Dock` executable and the Dock Tile icons for Finder in the Dock are located in `/System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/Resources`, thus making this just a normal working part of the Dock.app. It is one of two Dock Tiles, the other being the Trash, in which the position on the Dock cannot be changed due to being hard coded within the Dock executable.

Comment: What XML editor is that, yo?

Comment: @Spencer Williams, the picture of the com.apple.dock.plist file is of a window in Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

The apps you see in the Dock are displayed programmatically from data stored in a property list (.plist) at this path:

**/Users/<your_user_name>/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Dock.plist**

There is no folder of 'shortcuts'.