# There is a tiny icon on macOS dock that is not clickable!

Tags: macos, dock, mojave

After Visual Studio Code update, its icon on Dock has changed to a very tiny one which is literally inaccessible!

There is no way you can click on it or view options.

Does anyone know how to remove it from the Dock?

macOS: Mojave (10.14)

[image: VS Code tiny icon]

Comment: @Buscar웃 That's Microsoft's Remote Desktop app. Also, that tiny icon looks hilarious!

Comment: LOL, THIS IS HILARIOUS

Comment: interesting, the same thing happened to my Visual Studio code

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Edit** As pointed by many others (@nitive's comment below) there is a much easier way to fix this and it is `killall Dock`. Kudos to @nitive

---

**Original long, boring, and not so efficient answer**

LOL right after posting it, I found the answer

Fist: open the Dock config (plist):

```
open ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Dock.plist
```

Second: Find the item in `persistent-apps`:
[image: VS Code]

Third: Delete the item! In this case, "Item 14"

Forth: Save the file

Fifth: kill the Dock to force it to restart

Honestly, I was expecting it not to have the VS Code icon anymore but magically the icon reappeared there with the right size!

Comment: "Delete that row" -- item 14 itself? Or a particular entry under it?

Comment: @BallpointBen the entire item 14

Comment: Omg I think this answer in reverse may help to create dividers for a diff question lol

Comment: Just restarting Dock (via `killall Dock`) was enough for me and [a few other people](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/63068). No need to edit plist file

Comment: Thanks @Nitive for pointing out command to kill dock (`killall Dock`), I think it should be in original answer

Comment: @naffiq yes it must be

Comment: killall Dock command from terminal worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

I'd recommend removing the app from the dock and then opening it again, that should restore the correct icon. There are a few ways to remove an app from the dock:

1. If you can left click the icon you can drag it out.
2. If you can't drag you can Ctrl+Click and choose Options > Keep in Dock.
3. If no clicking is possible you can [manually edit the dock plist file](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/268087/in-what-folder-are-dock-applications-are-stored).

Comment: Thanks @andrew, the only way possible was the step 3 that I came across too. Very strange bug.

Answer (score 5):

```
 > killall Dock
```

This should work like charm, nothing else is needed. Restart your Dock.